# SQL Server : Query execution time depends on how many times query is executed

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, execution

I am trying to execute a rather "big" query on a SQL Server database :

```
SELECT *, (SELECT MAX(data) FROM another_sample_table) as max_data
FROM sample_test_1 st1
    LEFT JOIN sample_table_2 st2 ON (st2.date = st1.date)
    LEFT JOIN sample_table_3 st3 ON (st3.id = st2.id)
    LEFT JOIN sample_table_4 st4 ON (st4.code = st1.code)
    -- Two ohter LEFT JOINs
WHERE st1.date = '2000-01-01'
    AND st4.code IN ('EX1') -- and a list of code
```

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR :**

The query, when executed for the first time takes about 1 minute. **I think it is a matter of indexes**. The expected behavior should be that every time the query is executed, execution time should be more or less around 1 minute.

**ACTUAL RESULTS:**

The execution time becomes 1 second when the query is executed for the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc. time.

**QUESTION:**

Which technical aspect of SQL Server 2008 could explain such behavior ? Does the database save the results in a kind of cache for a certain amount of time then deletes it ? Or is it the `SELECT MAX(data) FROM another_sample_table` query that is causing some trouble ?

Comment: 'warming the buffer cache' - i.e. reading data from disk into memory

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have a look at [Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> SQL Server has a pool of memory that is used to store both execution
>   plans and data buffers. The percentage of the pool allocated to either
>   execution plans or data buffers fluctuates dynamically, depending on
>   the state of the system. The part of the memory pool that is used to
>   store execution plans is referred to as the procedure cache.

Comment: compiling the plan shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds even on a slow system. So that would not explain a difference of 1 minute to 1 second.

Comment: @MitchWheat, this is true, but as noted in the comment extract it can also store data buffers, which might help with the *improved performance*

Comment: which is what I said in my comment to the OP. Your answer suggests it's the query plan cache rather than the buffer cache.